# How to Add antsense protocol for ns2.35?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, ns2, ant-colony

I'm working on `ns2.35/ubuntu 14.04 LTS`.
I want to add `ant-sense` (ant colony optimization ) module in NS2 I have made changes to make file for  `INCLUDES & OBJ_CC`. And when type make in the terminal get this error

> make: gcc command not found
>
> make : *** [tcp/linux/tcp_naivereno.o] error 127

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like make does not know where gcc is located.

**Try this:**

Type `gcc --version`. If nothing displays, then you need to go find your gcc executable.

**Once you have found the gcc executable...**

`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/gcc/executable`.

After that, running `make` should work.